# Using Geometry Nodes to create and plot equations / functions

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

I know we can plot equations / functions with the `Math Function` - `XYZ Math Surface` Option in Blender  and then use a `Screw Modifier` to make it 3D see image below.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

I would like to do this using **Geometry Nodes** so I can adjust the values / equation dynamically to see how different values will effect the plot.  I know Animation Nodes can do this but the **goal is to do this in Geometry Nodes**.  Any thoughts / ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: AFAIK this isn’t possible „only“ with GN right now - but of course you could rebuild the math equations with nodes, but if i understood you right - you don’t want that.

Comment: @Chris if I build this with nodes (`not sure the difference between nodes and geometry nodes is`) will this allow the mesh to be dynamically changed?  How can this be done? Any examples to look at to see if it will create what I'm trying to do?

Comment: i meant math (geometry) nodes of course... ;)

Comment: Another way to add the math nodes.
Math Formula addon v1.2.0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=II_0Ep1z-Ks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could e.g. use this node setup:

I basically use index as x value (just multiply/add it so that it looks nicer), and here just a simple x*x function

[image]

or a sin - function:

[image]

and here an example of a 3d function:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can rebuild this equation using a bunch of math nodes:

[image]

Build the line and offset Y by this equation