# Replacing float curve node used to indent cylinder with a curve generated from equation

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

Replacing **float curve node** used to indent cylinder with a **curve generated from equation**.

I have two sections of geometry nodes that are **working separately in different blend files**.

The first part indents a cylinder based on a **float curve node**
[see link for history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254732/creating-an-indented-pipe-using-geometry-nodes/254766#254766)...

[image: img1]

The second part creates a curve based on an equation (**it uses just part of the equation generated**)
[see link for history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248789/using-geometry-nodes-to-create-and-plot-equations-functions)

**Note: the equation part is necessary because I plan on 3d printing different versions out for testing to see the effects on water (ORP / Ph).  Without me knowing the variables being used in the equations it would be hard for me to document what values caused what changes.**
[image: img2]

I would like to replace the **float curve node** that does the indenting in the first part with the **curve generated equation in the second part**.  How can this be done?

Note: This can probably be done using the screw and the shrink wrap modifier, along with extruding and insetting different parts, but the goal is to use geometry nodes to make it procedural along with having the ability to **use different equations**.

I've attached the blend files that includes both parts.  **Sorry for posting google drive links, I'll upload using blend-exchange once the issues have been fixed** (and yes I posted a [bug report](https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/issues) and he/she/they are looking into the blend-exchange posting attachment issue)

[image: img issue]

**Blend Files Below:**

[indent tube and spiral equation combo not working gn.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_KkzOBlaHVf8uqWyYeGFtJhhpboAstX8/view?usp=sharing)

[indent tube wrking gn.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u2IVi_8K8mZx-HitOm2RRT3qoFt7Bd4d/view?usp=sharing)

[spiral equation wrking gn.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jwb9dvScXzQrJljU7tqH-tQquTslipvG/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using Blender 3.1.0 beta

Comment: That's very cool !!! and looks very clean but the main goal is to use equations to test Viktor Schauberger theories. I plan on `3d printing different versions out for testing to see if they work and the effects.  Without knowing the variables in the equations it would be hard for me to document what values caused which changes.  But that is very cool!!!`

Comment: @Zero Dean .. thanks for the heads up on the broken link.