# How do I create a 3D parametric surface using Geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260404/how-do-i-plot-a-2d-parametric-equation-in-geometry-nodes) asked how to plot the graph of 2D [parametric equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) using Geometry Nodes.  But how about [parametric *surfaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_surface) generated by parametric equations of the form

$$ x = f(u, v)$$
$$ y = g(u, v)$$
$$ z = h(u, v)$$
$$ a \le u \le b$$
$$ c \le v \le d$$

like this parametric "figure 8" immersion [Klein Bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle):

[image: parametric Klein Bottle]

I know there are other methods for doing this.  For example, I can use the XYZ Math Surface option, this time using both $u$ and $v$ rather than just $u$ for a curve:

[image: parametric equations for the figure 8 immersion Klein bottle.]

But how do I do this with geometry nodes?

NOTE: this is not a question about surfaces where z is a direct function of x and y (those represented by $z = f(x,y)$) but about equations were $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all calculated as functions of two other variables, $u$ and $v$.  The difficulty arises from the fact that you can't solve these using an (x, y) grid.

Comment: For diplomacy's sake, if you  agree with me about the equivalence of @LuckyOne 's answer, and my later one, and they do answer your question satisfactorily, I would be very happy if you ticked his, not mine :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Your wish is my command.  I've upvoted both answers, but I'll wait for a day or two to see if anyone comes up with a solution that doesn't have the normals problem; but if a better answer doesn't show I'll except LuckyOne's.

Comment: I'll try to figure out the normals thing.... but atm I can't think of a fix. Maybe if I do a bit of washing-up or ironing :) ....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because your formula was too complicated for me...i just took another formula (but the principle is the same)

so here is an example:

[image]

I took the example from math surface -> cosinus

formula:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Will this way do? It's actually the same as @LuckyOne's, and the 2D answer you refer to. Instead of starting with a curve, start with a 'UV' grid, at the desired resolutions. Map the dimensions of the grid to the desired ranges of U and V.

Use the U(X) and V(Y) *Position*s of the grid's points as the inputs to your expressions for X', Y' and Z'. This is a lazy reproduction of your XYZ surface, imitating your helper functions:

[image]

(Excuse the spaghetti.) )In this case, I couldn't figure out how to take the twist out of the normals,though, without applying the modifier and <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> recalculating:

[image]

[Here's the .blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/dffc2971643f48f7a782b4a13e4027e8)

Comment: Don't put too much effort into figuring out the twist. I think it's an artifact of the object being a Klein bottle.  XYZ Surface leaves the same twist in the same place.