# How can I plot this Cartesian Equation in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

Can someone show me a picture of the nodes for the following equation?

$$ \left(x - x\left(\frac{z}a\right)\right)^2 + \left(y - y\left(\frac{z}a\right)\right)^2 = r^2 $$

Comment: Please take a closer look at the node `Math` (you can find it in the group "Utilities") and show us what progress you could make. ...I think the node is quite useful in this case.

Comment: https://im.ge/i/Fh8Y8P

Comment: maybe you should watch some beginner GN tutorials....e.g. from Erindale or Johnny Matthews. if you fail on this you will have problems with GN anyway because it is a lot of math...

Comment: You can use a driver method if the expression is complex.

Comment: No, don't use drivers in geometry nodes! It uses python, you'll lose performance a lot here

Comment: Don't use geometry nodes for this.  There is a built-in addon specifically for creating math surfaces.  It performs much better and you simply have to give it the equation.

Comment: Does [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260497/how-do-i-create-a-3d-parametric-surface-using-geometry-nodes) have a suitable answer?

Comment: what is `a` and `r`? Is it defined?

Answer (score 4):

The following [Cartesian Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) is of [Implicit Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function).

$$ \left(x - x\left(\frac{z}a\right)\right)^2 + \left(y - y\left(\frac{z}a\right)\right)^2 = r^2 $$

Quoting from [What are Implicit Equations](https://www.quora.com/What-are-implicit-equations):

> Let's say that $y$ is the dependent variable and $x$ is the independent
> variable. An **explicit solution** would be $y=f(x)$, i.e. $y$ is expressed in terms of $x$ only.
>
> An **implicit solution** is when you have $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ which means
> that $y$ and $x$ are mixed together. $y$ is not expressed in terms of
> $x$ only. You can have $x$ and $y$ on both sides of the equal sign or
> you can have $y$ on one side and $x,y$ on the other side. An example
> of implicit solution is $y=x(x+y)^2$

Thus you cannot directly use this type of equation from the Cartesian coordinate system in Geometry Nodes. Points in Euclidean space can be written in either Cartesian or the [Polar Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (extended into [Cylindrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) and [Spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) Coordinate System). In order for the equation to be usable in your case, it needs to be transformed into a form called [Parametric Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) which operate on the 3D Polar Coordinate System. That is, it needs to be of the form:
$$ x = x(u, v)$$
$$ y = y(u, v)$$
$$ z = z(u, v)$$

You may be able to simplify the original equation to:
$$(x^2+y^2)(1−(z/a))^2=r^2$$
But note that the term $1−(z/a)$ is **unbounded** and thus this equation has **infinite** potential solutions for possible equations as long as they satisfy the original cartesian equation. [Please see one solution I have prepared on the Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500955/how-to-convert-a-cartesian-equation-to-parametric-equation). Here I have prepared one (1) of many possible sets of solutions from the family of circular base solutions.

$$x=r\cos{u}\sin{v}$$
$$y=r\sin{u}\sin{v}$$
$$z=a\pm\frac{a}{\sin{v}}$$

> Note from the solution provided in the math link:
>
> - In the above results, for this particular form only, $z=z(v)$ only.
> - In general, $z=z(u,v)$ as long as it satisfies Eq. (6).
> - We can solve Eq. (6), as a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) because, we can also assume that $z=z(v)$ for illustrative purposes only.
> - In other words, there can be many other forms of solutions as long as they satisfy Eq. (6), for the same equations for $x=x(u,v)$ and
>   $y=y(u,v)$, given by Eq. (3).

Now you are able to use these parametric equations in Geometry Nodes similarly solved as to [Robin Bett's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260503/142292):

[image]

Here's the resulting graph for this particular set of solution:

[image]

[One Possible Solution Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500955/how-to-convert-a-cartesian-equation-to-parametric-equation)

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. You give every appearance of being a proper mathematician!  ;)

Comment: hahaha thank you but it was also with the assistance of a PhD friend. I was really eager to know the solution so I had to do some digging ! :D

Comment: Wonderful! I, as a non-mathematician, can only judge what I see. What I see is wonderful!

Comment: @quellenform thank you! :) hey btw thanks also for the re-open vote! without it i couldnt have shared it XD

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need a tree of nodes that embodies this particular formula?
[image]
All these nodes are actually one node - math node.