# How to Animate Grid into Parametric Surface?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270409/how-can-i-plot-this-cartesian-equation-in-geometry-nodes)'s answer a parametric surface was created from a simple *Grid* node using the *Set Position* node. That means it should be possible to animate each vertex from its original position in the Grid to its final position in the parametric surface. Is it possible to animate this grid into a parametric shape with a nice wrapping animation? I would like to have a Grid nicely animate and wrap around into that shape or into a Torus, whatever is simpler. It would probably require some delay between animtion of each vertex index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use color mix to blend coordinates:

[image]

Use *scene time* and *multiply add* to control animation speed:

[image]

To add row by row offset, add X or Y original coordinate to scene time and use *multiply add* to control speed:

[image]

Comment: hey thanks! that's pretty cool !