# GN: How to smooth out jagged edges after deleting geometry?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, mathematics

In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271833/how-to-render-y-x-1-y-x12-4y-1-2-2-in-blender/) I have prepared this Geometry Nodes setup to represent the following function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\,\left( y - x + 1 - \sqrt{\left(y-x+1\right)^2 -4y}\,\right) $$

where
$$0<=x<=1$$
$$0<=y<=1$$

But the *Delete Geometry* node will result in jagged edges. Is there another way to use Geometry Nodes to have smoother edges, perhaps without this *Delete Geometry* node or maybe by merging vertices?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As always, I could be wrong, but when I mapped this function at high resolution and magnified over a small domain, the jagged edges appeared to be an accurate representation of it, not a sampling error? If that's the case, (and you're not wanting to represent this function) why not choose another function?

Comment: Hi Robin, nice that you mentioned it! It made me realize you are actually right and there is no problem! This is the boundary of imaginary and real numbers 

Comment: you can post it as answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Phew! That's good. I won't post.. it's a bit niche to be useful to the archive, I think. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: cool no prob. glad to know the answer. it was getting weird that even at a 2000 x 2000 resolution it was jagged but is accurate after all :)

Comment: why are you deleting the geometry in the first place? doesn't the set position give it its shape?