# Using math nodes to create geometry in geometry nodes

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

Using math nodes to create geometry in geometry nodes

I'm trying to create some geometry **using math nodes in geometry nodes see image below of what I'm trying to create.**  *Yes I know I could model a half circle and a line to get it but the goal is to use an equation to make it parametric*.

[image: img0]

I can create a sine wave.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

But when I try and use **greater than 0 node** I get what looks to be the start of a square wave.

[image: im3]

Attached Blend file below
[image]

Comment: Does [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260497/how-do-i-create-a-3d-parametric-surface-using-geometry-nodes) or [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260404/how-do-i-plot-a-2d-parametric-equation-in-geometry-nodes) answer your question?

Comment: I saw those.  My main issue was with using the greater than node instead of maximum node.  Still not fully sure why the greater than node didn't work but I'll have to look it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The greater than Math node returns 1 (greater than) or 0 (smaller or equal).

You probably want the Maximum option instead of the Greater than:

[image: Maximum math node]

note that clamping a sine wave will not give you half circles, for that you will need other formula:

$$
\begin{cases} 
    0 & \texttt{if } M> 2r \\
    \sqrt{r^{2}-\left ( M-r \right )^{2}} & \texttt{if } M \leq 2r
\end{cases}
$$
$$$$

- $\mathbf{M}=\operatorname{mod}\left(x+r,\ 2r+s\right)$
- $\mathbf{r}=\text{radius}$
- $\mathbf{s}=\text{spacing}$

[image: Geo nodes half circle wave 1]

[image: half circle wave 1]

Or since you know the cirlce radius and the spacing between, you can put vertices in optimal positions:
[image: Geo nodes half circle wave 2]

[image: half circle wave 2]

Comment: Wonderful! I know the rule that says not to sing the praises and thanks here, but this is just great!

Comment: I was just about to do y=sin(ax)+sin(y)) with a maximum node and call it a day hahah....then I saw yours WOW!!!....I'm going to try and work your solution out just to see if I can fully understand it.

Comment: @RickT I did the formula using desmos, take a look if you find it easier to understand with a graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qcyponl18l

Comment: Will do, desmos is a great site!